# TestLink - How do I reassign a test case to a different tester

Tags: testlink

I've just started using TestLink to manage testing, and a test plan containing a number of test suites and test cases is currently being executed. One of my testers is a bit overwhelmed by the number of test cases I've assigned him. How can I reassign some of his test cases to another team member?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to go to project overview and click on "Assign Test Case Execution" in the right panel. Then select the test cases or test suites you want to reassign and the application will show you the TC information, assigned to and assign to fields.

Select the new assignee and click on "Save". Also, bulk upload functionality is available.

That's all.